# MySQL, put second table into another table

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I'm new to mysql. I have two tables (tableA, tableB). I would like to construct a query to retrieve data where retrieved data would have table B as a field in table A, like this:

```
{
    tableA_key1: tableA_value1,
    tableA_key2: tableA_value2,
    tableA_key3: tableA_value3, // ...all key-value pairs from table A
    additional_data: {
        tableB_key1: tableB_value1,
        tableB_key2: tableB_value2,
        tableB_key3: tableB_value3, // ...all key-value pairs from table B
    }
}
```

In other words to nest second table as an additional object in the first table. I've tried JOIN operators but that makes the structure flat?
How can I nest tables like in the schema above?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Yes, but then I would need to run two separate queries?

Comment: No. You'd just parse the array returned from a single, simple query

Comment: Can you write an example of that kind of query? Thank you in advance

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 5.7 or higher, you can use JSON like this:

```
select a.*,
    json_object(
        'tableB_key1', b.tableB_key1,
        'tableB_key2', b.tableB_key2
    ) as additional_data
from tablea a
inner join tableb b on ....
```

This puts a JSON object representing the matching record in a new column, called `additional_data`. You need to enumerate all the key/value pairs that need to go in that object.

If there may be multiple matches, you might want to consider using an array instead:

```
select a.*,
    json_arrayagg(json_object(
        'tableB_key1', b.tableB_key1,
        'tableB_key2', b.tableB_key2
    )) as additional_data
from tablea a
inner join tableb b on ....
group by a.id
```

Comment: sir from which websites we learn these things.

Comment: @KUMAR: the [MySQL JSON documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) is a good place to start...

Comment: The only strange thing is that mysql return string instead or real object